# Synonymize [google-linechart] with [google-visualization]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There are 30 different chart types in [Googles Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery). We do not need a separate tag for each of them. I suggest we synonymize [google-linechart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-linechart) with [google-visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-visualization).